# system wide keyboard hook on X under linux

Tags: linux

What would be the best approach to install a keyboard hook on Linux (X-windows) in order to trigger some application when some key-combo is pressed?? Is there a way to do this regardless of which window manager is running? The idea is to have an application being called ( or brought to foreground ) when some key is pressed in a way similar that Google Desktop does to Ctrl-Ctrl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XGrabKey` on the root window is how xbindkey does it. Be careful about having some alternative method of killing the grab though, it's very annoying to have to go somewhere to `ssh` into your own box just to kill that process... And that's why, if it was me, `xbindkeys`+"echo 'moo' > /tmp/moo-fifo" would be the way to do it. That way, you could also control it in any number of other ways you haven't thought of yet.