# Global Keyboard Hook in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, hook, global

How to write global keyboard hook in Ubuntu (Linux) (like Hook for Windows)

In C/C++ or Python

Comment: Please search SO before asking a question. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144901/system-wide-keyboard-hook-on-x-under-linux) for your answer.

Comment: Nope. It's not a dupe. That post it a dead end.