# Get Keyboard input c++ outside of terminal

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a c++ program that responds to keyboard input. I want to run this as a daemon so I can't use cin, I would also like to output each character as it is pressed to a picoLCD screen that I have set up. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the application is running in the background as a daemon, you can use the common Windows approach of a "keyboard hook". This is performed much differently on Linux though and there are various methods you may want to look into.

It is discussed a bit in this SO question: [system wide keyboard hook on X under linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144901/system-wide-keyboard-hook-on-x-under-linux)

Comment: Thanks not exactly what I am looking for but got me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the Framework API and OS, but the [picoLCD](http://www.mini-box.com/picoLCD-20x2-OEM) states that it should show up as a standard keyboard (or HID) device. If straight C/C++ getchar() or cin.