# How to grab 'key-press-event' when the window is not focused?

Tags: c, gtk

I am writing a program using gtk. What the program does is monitor the keystroke the user entered and play a sound. My question is that how do I catch the key-press-event when the window is not focused? I'm planning to let my program stay in tray icon, so I wonder how I can grab any key-press-event from there. Thanks

Edit:
I finally find a way to do it - The XTest extension, I found the a piece of code snippet from the program 'xmacro'.
You can see my implementation here:
http://github.com/Aitjcize/Qwertickle/blob/master/src/qwertickle.c

btw, it's still quite buggy, maybe someone can help me out? :)

Comment: @pmg: Why would a keylogger play a sound...? Furthermore why would you keylog <1% of desktop users when you can get 90% by writing some Win32?

Comment: I'm all FOR people writing keyloggers, viruses, trojans, worms and whatnot. I've never felt the interest in writing one myself, but if I knew how to, I'd, at least, point Aitjcize in the right direction (and "keylogger" might just be what he/she needs to get results from his/her preferred search engine)

Comment: @pmg: I was going to write something like this http://www.nattyware.com/qwertick.php in Linux, = =.

Comment: I think the question is reasonable, just think of desktop wide hotkeys for application launchers and stuff

Comment: Okay now I'm interested. This kind of thing isn't as easy in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Matt Joiner said,

> This kind of thing isn't as easy in Linux.

and unfortunately GTK+ can't do this kind of magic.

You should take a look at [XEvIE](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XEvIE) - X Event Interception Extension - it will make your job easier.

> XEvIE is a X extension providing functionalities to allow users intercept keyboard/mouse events.

**And** as suggested by [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144901/system-wide-keyboard-hook-on-x-under-linux), another way to go would be to use [XGrabKey()](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKey.html)/[XUngrabKey()](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XUngrabKey.html) from X11. I believe that [tinywm](http://incise.org/tinywm.html) shows how to use it correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! At last I used the XTst extension, I found it in xmacro's source code. You can find my implementation here: http://github.com/Aitjcize/Qwertickle/blob/master/src/qwertickle.c

Comment: @Aitjcize: That's very nice code you've written. Your switch on the key pressed would be more readable if you used character literals: `case 65` can be `case 'A'` for example.

Comment: A great answer, lots of links for further reading, well done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called xbindkeys that can bind mouse and keyboard keys in X to launch shell commands. You can either utilize this to send commands to your program, or look at the sourcecode to see how its done: [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html)

You can also directly open /dev/input/eventX and read() from it to an input_event struct, but thats a little nasty, because you need to have the proper rights (normally root, or change it with chmod)

Comment: Reading /dev/input/event* doesn't work if X's evdev drive has it grabbed.