# Disable shortcut keys in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I need some tips in how can I disable shortcut keys in Linux (Ubuntu), while running an application. I need simple application, which when is started all the shortcut keys are disabled, including ctrl+c,ctrl+v,alt+tab, etc. I need Java implementation. After exiting the application, everything should be normal again. Any help will be useful, also and some simple code :)

Regards

Comment: no one wants to lose control while running your application. Every game that sucks prevents alt+tab.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a cross-platform environment, so it *avoids any system-specific libraries*. However, you can use **[JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)** to call program in C or anything else, that will actually set hooks.

But note, that it really sucks, if the user cannot use Alt-Tab.

UPD. There's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144901/system-wide-keyboard-hook-on-x-under-linux) on SO, that describes hot to better grab keystrokes in X.