# Linux X11 - Global Keyboard Hook

Tags: c++, linux, hook, x11

Is it possible (or how) to create a mechanism (in Linux X11, C++) that works like a global hook in windows (SetWindowsHookEx())?

I would like to be able to catch the key event but with the **possibility of further propagation**. I'm trying to use a [**XGrabKey**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144901/system-wide-keyboard-hook-on-x-under-linux) solution (like in [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html)) but when I set capturing the key event, this event is "consumed".

Requirements for this mechanism are the following:

1. **Global / system-wide - catching events regardless of the window that has focus**
2. **The possibility of "catch-hold" and "catch-pass through"**
3. **It must be quite fast**

Sample code looks like this:

```
bool myFlagIsSet = false;
XEvent event;
while (true) {
    while (XPending(display) > 0) {
        usleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    }

    XNextEvent(display, &event);
    switch (e.type) {
        case KeyPress:
            if (myFlagIsSet) {
                //do not propagate
            }
            // propagate
            break;
        case KeyRelease:
            if (myFlagIsSet) {
                //do not propagate
            }
            // propagate
            break;
    }
}
```

On Windows I simply wrote:

```
if(event.isConsumed()) {
    return LRESULT(1);
}
//...
return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
```

I've also tried using XUngrabKey and XSendEvent:

```
switch (event.type) {
    case KeyPress:
        if (myFlagIsSet) {
            //do not propagate
        }
        // propagate
        XUngrabKey(...);
        XSendEvent(..., &event);
        XGrabKey(...);
        break;
    case KeyRelease:
        ...
    }
```

Unfortunately XSendEvent for unknown reasons to me - do not send this event even if XGrabKey line is commented.

Is it possible to successfully complete this approach?

Please suggest some other approach if I am condemned to failure

**EDIT**

I would like to implement this on Ubuntu Gnome using Compiz Window Manager

Comment: This functionality will depend on the window manager/desktop environment you're using.

Comment: Hey @Xeon were you able to find a solution? I am trying to do the same exact thing. (I prefer xcb though because I can run it off the mainthread.)

Comment: @Noitidart unfortunately I couldn't.

Comment: Dang @Xeon, I was able to succesfully do this with `gdk_add_window_filter` however it only works while the windows of the calling app are active. It wasn't global. Apparently, per this users comment, xcb works global after changing window properties on the root, however I can't get it to work. It might work for your - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906243/no-error-on-xcb-grab-key-but-event-loop-not-catching-global-hotkey#comment59569752_35906243

Comment: Does XPeekEvent solves your problem? https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XNextEvent.3.xhtml

Answer (score 6):

Try compile easy code from this page:

http://webhamster.ru/site/page/index/articles/comp/367

It's sample of get global keyboard event. This small app working as **xinput**.

**Remark 1:** Write device ID to mian.cpp (get ID by running xinput without parameters):

```
sprintf(deviceId, "9");
```

**Remark 2:** Compile command:

```
gcc ./main.cpp -lstdc++ -lX11 -lXext -lXi
```

**Remakr 3:** Before compile, install libxi-dev package:

```
apt-get install libxi-dev
```

File **main.h**

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XInput.h>

#ifdef HAVE_XI2
#include <X11/extensions/XInput2.h>
#endif

#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int xi_opcode; /* xinput extension op code */

XDeviceInfo* find_device_info( Display *display, char *name, Bool only_extended);

#if HAVE_XI2
XIDeviceInfo* xi2_find_device_info(Display *display, char *name);
int xinput_version(Display* display);
#endif
```

File **main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

#include "main.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int xi_opcode;

#define INVALID_EVENT_TYPE -1

static int motion_type = INVALID_EVENT_TYPE;
static int button_press_type = INVALID_EVENT_TYPE;
static int button_release_type = INVALID_EVENT_TYPE;
static int key_press_type = INVALID_EVENT_TYPE;
static int key_release_type = INVALID_EVENT_TYPE;
static int proximity_in_type = INVALID_EVENT_TYPE;
static int proximity_out_type = INVALID_EVENT_TYPE;

static int register_events(Display *dpy,
                           XDeviceInfo *info,
                           char *dev_name,
                           Bool handle_proximity)
{
    int            number = 0;    /* number of events registered */
    XEventClass        event_list[7];
    int            i;
    XDevice        *device;
    Window        root_win;
    unsigned long    screen;
    XInputClassInfo    *ip;

    screen = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    root_win = RootWindow(dpy, screen);

    device = XOpenDevice(dpy, info->id);

    if (!device) {
    printf("unable to open device '%s'\n", dev_name);
    return 0;
    }

    if (device->num_classes > 0) {
    for (ip = device->classes, i=0; i<info->num_classes; ip++, i++) {
        switch (ip->input_class) {
        case KeyClass:
        DeviceKeyPress(device, key_press_type, event_list[number]); number++;
        DeviceKeyRelease(device, key_release_type, event_list[number]); number++;
        break;

        case ButtonClass:
        DeviceButtonPress(device, button_press_type, event_list[number]); number++;
        DeviceButtonRelease(device, button_release_type, event_list[number]); number++;
        break;

        case ValuatorClass:
        DeviceMotionNotify(device, motion_type, event_list[number]); number++;
        if (handle_proximity) {
            ProximityIn(device, proximity_in_type, event_list[number]); number++;
            ProximityOut(device, proximity_out_type, event_list[number]); number++;
        }
        break;

        default:
        printf("unknown class\n");
        break;
        }
    }

    if (XSelectExtensionEvent(dpy, root_win, event_list, number)) {
        printf("error selecting extended events\n");
        return 0;
    }
    }
    return number;
}


static void print_events(Display *dpy)
{
    XEvent        Event;

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);

    while(1) {
    XNextEvent(dpy, &Event);

    if (Event.type == motion_type) {
        int    loop;
        XDeviceMotionEvent *motion = (XDeviceMotionEvent *) &Event;

        printf("motion ");

        for(loop=0; loop<motion->axes_count; loop++) {
        printf("a[%d]=%d ", motion->first_axis + loop, motion->axis_data[loop]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else if ((Event.type == button_press_type) ||
           (Event.type == button_release_type)) {
        int    loop;
        XDeviceButtonEvent *button = (XDeviceButtonEvent *) &Event;

        printf("button %s %d ", (Event.type == button_release_type) ? "release" : "press  ",
           button->button);

        for(loop=0; loop<button->axes_count; loop++) {
        printf("a[%d]=%d ", button->first_axis + loop, button->axis_data[loop]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else if ((Event.type == key_press_type) ||
           (Event.type == key_release_type)) {
        int    loop;
        XDeviceKeyEvent *key = (XDeviceKeyEvent *) &Event;

        printf("key %s %d ", (Event.type == key_release_type) ? "release" : "press  ",
           key->keycode);

        for(loop=0; loop<key->axes_count; loop++) {
        printf("a[%d]=%d ", key->first_axis + loop, key->axis_data[loop]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else if ((Event.type == proximity_out_type) ||
           (Event.type == proximity_in_type)) {
        int    loop;
        XProximityNotifyEvent *prox = (XProximityNotifyEvent *) &Event;

        printf("proximity %s ", (Event.type == proximity_in_type) ? "in " : "out");

        for(loop=0; loop<prox->axes_count; loop++) {
        printf("a[%d]=%d ", prox->first_axis + loop, prox->axis_data[loop]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("what's that %d\n", Event.type);
    }
    }
}


// Определение версии библиотеки расширений, установленной для X11
int xinput_version(Display    *display)
{
    XExtensionVersion    *version;
    static int vers = -1;

    if (vers != -1)
        return vers;

    version = XGetExtensionVersion(display, INAME);

    if (version && (version != (XExtensionVersion*) NoSuchExtension)) {
    vers = version->major_version;
    XFree(version);
    }

#if HAVE_XI2
    /* Announce our supported version so the server treats us correctly. */
    if (vers >= XI_2_Major)
    {
        const char *forced_version;
        int maj = 2,
            min = 0;

#if HAVE_XI22
        min = 2;
#elif HAVE_XI21
        min = 1;
#endif

        forced_version = getenv("XINPUT_XI2_VERSION");
        if (forced_version) {
            if (sscanf(forced_version, "%d.%d", &maj, &min) != 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid format of XINPUT_XI2_VERSION "
                                "environment variable. Need major.minor\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("Overriding XI2 version to: %d.%d\n", maj, min);
        }

        XIQueryVersion(display, &maj, &min);
    }
#endif

    return vers;
}


// Поиск информации об устройстве
XDeviceInfo* find_device_info(Display *display,
                              char *name,
                              Bool only_extended)
{
    XDeviceInfo *devices;
    XDeviceInfo *found = NULL;
    int        loop;
    int        num_devices;
    int        len = strlen(name);
    Bool    is_id = True;
    XID        id = (XID)-1;

    for(loop=0; loop<len; loop++) {
    if (!isdigit(name[loop])) {
        is_id = False;
        break;
    }
    }

    if (is_id) {
    id = atoi(name);
    }

    devices = XListInputDevices(display, &num_devices);

    for(loop=0; loop<num_devices; loop++) {
    if ((!only_extended || (devices[loop].use >= IsXExtensionDevice)) &&
        ((!is_id && strcmp(devices[loop].name, name) == 0) ||
         (is_id && devices[loop].id == id))) {
        if (found) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Warning: There are multiple devices named '%s'.\n"
                    "To ensure the correct one is selected, please use "
                    "the device ID instead.\n\n", name);
        return NULL;
        } else {
        found = &devices[loop];
        }
    }
    }
    return found;
}


int test(Display *display, char *deviceId)
{
    XDeviceInfo *info;

    Bool handle_proximity = True;

    info = find_device_info(display, deviceId, True);

    if(!info)
    {
      printf("unable to find device '%s'\n", deviceId);
      exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
      if(register_events(display, info, deviceId, handle_proximity))
         print_events(display);
      else
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "no event registered...\n");
        exit(1);
      }
    }

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
  Display *display;
  int event, error;

  // Инициируется указатель на текущий дисплей
  display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  if (display == NULL)
  {
    printf("Unable to connect to X server\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // Проверяется наличие расширений
  if(!XQueryExtension(display, "XInputExtension", &xi_opcode, &event, &error))
  {
    printf("X Input extension not available.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // Проверяется версия расширения, она не должна быть нулевой
  if(!xinput_version(display))
  {
    printf("%s extension not available\n", INAME);
    exit(1);
  }

  char deviceId[10];
  sprintf(deviceId, "9");

  test(display, deviceId);

  XSync(display, False);
  XCloseDisplay(display);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use XTestFakeKeyEvent() from the [XTest extension library](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/Xext/xtestlib.pdf) to propagate fake key press / release events.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing this on the X11 level I recommend to do it on the input device level. `/dev/input/event<n>` give you the input events. You can read off the keypresses there and decide if they should propagate further or be consumed. Unfortunately there's no real documentation for this, but the header file `linux/include/input.h` is quite self explanatory. Also the evdev maintainer will gladly answer emails.

Comment: Not really an option at all if his code is not running as root, and you'd have to re-implement all the tricky keyboard junk the X server handles (layout, keycode mapping, etc), last, you'd have to deal with hotplug and the fact that the X server grabs the devices exclusively.

Comment: @Spudd86: The OP wants a **global** hook. To me global means, that it will take over all further processing. Yes this requires some dealing with hotplug, but this is not too complicated, either. The X server grabbing the device is no problem either. BTDT: a while back I coded such a "global hook" to catch my keyboard's multimedia keys but pass on the rest.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing, if you want to be able to refer to keys by the symbol printed on them you're gonna have to deal with all the madness that xkb does so you can get the layouts right. (Since you'd want it to be the same as whatever the X server is doing)

Answer (score 3):

`XSendEvent()` probably does send it; but as it's widely regarded as a security hole, most programs ignore UI events with the `send_event` flag set.

The standard X11 protocol doesn't allow this.  The XInput 2.0 extension might, but I doubt it; while Windows assumes a single event queue that every program listens to, so that a program can intercept an event and prevent it from being sent down the queue to other listeners, every X11 client has its own independent queue and all clients that register interest in an event receive an independent copy of it in their queue.  This means that under normal circumstances it's impossible for an errant program to block other programs from running; but it also means that, for those times when a client must block other clients, it must do a server grab to prevent the server from processing events for any other client.

Answer (score 1):

no idea if this helps, but I just found this in some code:

```
    void XFakeKeypress(Display *display, int keysym)
    { 
       XKeyEvent event;                     
       Window current_focus_window;         
       int current_focus_revert;

       XGetInputFocus(/* display = */ display, /* focus_return = */ 
          ¤t_focus_window, /* revert_to_return = */ ¤t_focus_revert);

       event.type = /* (const) */ KeyPress;
       event.display = display;
       event.window = current_focus_window;
       event.root = DefaultRootWindow(/* display = */ display);
       event.subwindow = /* (const) */ None;
       event.time = 1000 * time(/* tloc = */ NULL);
       event.x = 0;
       event.y = 0;
       event.x_root = 0;
       event.y_root = 0;
       event.state = /* (const) */ ShiftMask;   
       event.keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(/* display = */ display, 
          /* keysym = */ keysym);
       event.same_screen = /* (const) */ True;  

       XSendEvent(/* display = */ display, /* w = (const) */ InputFocus,
          /* propagate = (const) */ True, /* event_mask = (const) */ 
          KeyPressMask, /* event_send = */ (XEvent *)(&event));

       event.type = /* (const) */ KeyRelease;   
       event.time = 1000 * time(/* tloc = */ NULL);

       XSendEvent(/* display = */ display, /* w = (const) */ InputFocus,
          /* propagate = (const) */ True, /* event_mask = (const) */ 
          KeyReleaseMask, /* event_send = */ (XEvent *)(&event));
    }
```