# How to create global keyboard filter @ Linux?

Tags: linux, filter, keyboard, handler, global

In short - I need to implement global keyboard handler on Linux that works as follows:

```
if (pressedKey == lastpressedKey && timeElapsed < 100 msecs)
{
    Neutralize_KeyPress()
}
```

Long version - I recently bought Acer S7 laptop that suffers from a [keyboard issue](http://community.acer.com/t5/Ultra-Thin/Acer-s7-keyboard-issue-with-repeating-characters/td-p/24407) - keys are frequently and randomly repeated (repeat/delay settings don't fix the problem). Fortunately there is a [fix for Windows (#163)](http://forum.notebookreview.com/sony/306453-sony-vaio-z-sticky-squeaky-keys-doubled-type-17.html) and I would like to port it to Linux (Ubuntu 13.04).

I'm looking for system wide keyboard filter (I solved the problem in X just by enabling 'System Settings/Universal Access/Typing/Bounce Keys'). I Googled various key loggers that use /dev/input/event*, but they don't filter events. I also checked [Linux X11 - Global Keyboard Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560553/linux-x11-global-keyboard-hook) however, it doesn't give a good answer.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I would patch the X11 server, but I am not familiar enough with its internals to suggest how to do that. Maybe ask on [xorg@lists.x.org](http://lists.x.org/mailman/listinfo/xorg) ?

Comment: Thanks! After having shower I tried '$ xkbset bouncekeys 10' which seems to fix the problem in X. I will keep searching for console solution (or a better, system wide one)...

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question, so that other people could find your solution (comments might not be kept on the long run).

Comment: Sure, I will do that as soon as I tune xkbset options - the issue occured ~ every 15 characters, after fix ~80.