# Disable global hotkeys for window

Tags: linux, qt, qt4, xserver

I am making RDP GUI for myself and i would like all key combinations handled by RDP session. I use freerdp for handling RDP stuff, it has handy flag where i specify winId() of qt widged to embed RDP window to. Everything works except for few keys. For example window key still opens menu on host, not start menu in RDP session. Also alt-f2 opens gnome start screen instead of performing bound action in application inside RDP session. Is it possible to somehow make all key combinations to be handled only by embedded RDP window and not xserver?

I have tried following (Xlib/python):

```
window.change_attributes(do_not_propagate_mask=X.KeyPress | X.KeyRelease)
```

However that does not seem to change anything. I also tried disabling key events in qt without much luck. Truth to be told i do not know exactly if this has to be done at qt or X level. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Qt can't help you here. You should use native means. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144901/system-wide-keyboard-hook-on-x-under-linux.

Comment: Apparently im half-way there. I can do XGrabKeyboard() on main qt window but then widget with rdp view does not react to keyboard input. I thought maybe i should use winId() of widget but then Xlib throws exception about window (id?) being invalid. Any ideas how to approach this?